# Apollo: You are calling concat on a terminating link, which will have no effect

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am working in Apollo, GraphQL and Nuxtjs project, when setting up Apollo configuration I got this Warning:

```
link.js:38 Error: You are calling concat on a terminating link, which will have no effect
at new LinkError (linkUtils.js:41)
at concat (link.js:38)
at ApolloLink.webpackJsonp../node_modules/apollo-link/lib/link.js.ApolloLink.concat (link.js:65)
at link.js:13
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at from (link.js:13)
at createApolloClient (index.js:58)
at webpackJsonp../.nuxt/apollo-module.js.__webpack_exports__.a (apollo-module.js:66)
at _callee2$ (index.js:140)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
```

Here is my code:

```js
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

export default ({ store, env  }) => {
  const httpLink = new createHttpLink({ uri: env.GRAPH_BASE_URL });

  // middleware
  const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const token = store.getters['user/GET_TOKEN'];

    if (token) {
      operation.setContext({
        headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      });
    }

    return forward(operation);
  });

  const link = middlewareLink.concat(httpLink);

  return {
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  }
};
```

I Searched on Google for any similar issue, I found this one https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/issues/47
but it did not help me.
I tried to change:

```
const link = middlewareLink.concat(httpLink);
```

to:

```
const link = Apollo.from([middlewareLink, httpLink]);
```

but it still gives me the same warning,
any help please

Comment: take a look https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/composition.html#additive and 
https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql/blob/master/client/src/graphql/apollo-client.js

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The solution for me is putting `Http Link` at the end of the Apollo Link array (used when you're creating the Apollo Client).

```
...
const param = {
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(...) =>...,
    authLink...,
    new HttpLink({
      uri: '/graphql',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
  ]),
  cache: ...,
  connectToDevTools: ...
}

new ApolloClient(param);
```

---

I'm using these libraries:

- `apollo-client`
- `apollo-cache-inmemory`
- `apollo-link`
- `apollo-link-http`
- `apollo-link-context`
- `apollo-link-error`

Comment: Thanks, I solved the same way!, but I forget to put the answer, thank you for posting that.

Comment: What about the WebSocketLink? If you would want to have both http:// and ws:// links, which one would go last? 
Both http and ws are terminating links. Can't figure this one out.

Comment: Hi @aurinxki did you figure this out?

Comment: @phainix, I ended up replacing the httpLink with the wsLink. I found that both were terminating links in the documentation(https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-ws/, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/). 

When initializing the client, first had to chain errorlink and uploadLink errorLink.concat(uploadLink) into a const. 

Then 

link: from([
      chainedLink,
      wsLink
    ]),

Comment: Thanks @aurinxki, I used the apollo-client split, and it worked quite well. It splits into ws or http based on the type, the split is then used as the last link, you can check it out here (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#3-split-communication-by-operation-recommended)

Answer (score 22):

In my case, i solved the issue, changing the order in array, example:

Before:

```
const links = [...middlewares, localLink, authLink, httpLink, errorLink]
```

After:

```
const links = [...middlewares, localLink, authLink, errorLink, httpLink]
```

Comment: for me this order worked: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, middlewareLink, httpLink]);

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that in the vue-apollo readme there is some docs for the apolloClient configs and it says you can turn off defaultHttpLink to use terminating links.

```
return {
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
  defaultHttpLink: false, // this should do the trick
}
```

Comment: still facing this issue.

Comment: were you able to fix it? I'm still having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

The httplink should be a the end of the link array.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to make sure the errorLink is last. I wasn't using HttpLink but still got this error.

My order:

```js
const links = [errorLink, retryLink, uploadLink];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { createHttpLink, split } from '@apollo/client';

const finalLink = split(operation => operation.getContext().version === 1, httpLink, httpLink2);

return new Map()
    .set('MUTATION_QUEUE', mutationQueueLink)
    .set('RETRY', retryLink)
    .set('AUTH', authLink)
    .set('GQL_CACHE', gqlCacheLink)
    .set('ERROR', errorLink)
    .set('HTTP', finalLink);
```

---

I resolve my issue by using `split` function.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34418678)